# php - extracting url parameters for use in a proxy

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-services, proxy

Hi I'm trying to build a web proxy in PHP, but I want the script that builds it to accomodate parameters from the requesting URL so that the proxy URL is dynamic. How do I do this? This is my code:

soapFetch.php:

```
<?php
     die( file_get_contents( 'url.com/Spark/SparkService.asmx?op=LoginConsumer' ) );
 ?>
```

Right now, the op= parameter only accommodates one function, Login Consumer. But I want it to be able to support three functions: LoginConsumer, InsertConsumer, and UpdateConsumer. I would like to try to have it call the appropriate function based on whatever I passed to soapFetch.php - if I call soapFetch.php?op=InsertConsumer, it would call url.com/Spark/SparkService.asmx?op=InsertConsumer. If I call soapFetch.php?op=UpdateConsumer, it calls url.com/Spark/SparkService.asmx?op=UpdateConsumer, etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_GET["op"]` to get a parameter from the request, you can then pass it to your function.

E.g.

```
<?php
 die( file_get_contents( 'url.com/Spark/SparkService.asmx?op='.$_GET["op"] ) );
?>
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I can do within the soapFetch.php file to make the request for the web service URL more secure?

Comment: You could limit the possible values for `op` by checking that they will only be passed along if they are valid. E.g. if($op === "InsertConsumer" || $op === "UpdateConsumer" ...)